# Linear optimisation in python using cvxpy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cvxpy

this is a simple example of LP using cvxpy

```
import cvxpy as cp
x1 = cp.Variable()
x2 = cp.Variable()
objective = cp.Minimize(0.3*x1 + 0.4*x2)
constraints = [
    4.6*x1 + 58.8*x2 >= 300,
    52*x1 + 33*x2 >= 2000,
    152*x1 + 133*x2 >= 5000,
]
linear_program = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)
result = linear_program.solve()
```

my question is if I have the same constraints in the form of a dataFrame

```
A = pd.DataFrame([[4.6,58.8],[52,33],[152,133]])
c= [0.3,0.4]
b = [300,2000,5000]
```

then how do I transform A,b and c to put it through the cvxpy optimiser?
i.e.
converting the dataFrame A, b to the format

```
4.6*x1 + 58.8*x2 >= 300,
52*x1 + 33*x2 >= 2000,
152*x1 + 133*x2 >= 5000,
```

and c to

```
0.3*x1 + 0.4*x2
```

Its easy to manually type if the number of constraints and variable are limited (3 and 2 in this case), but my acutal problem has over 50+ variables and over 80+ constraints in the form of dataFrames (and the numbers can keep changing so I cant hardcode the constraints).

#########Edits-
updated the shape of the dataFrame A, which was previously incorrect

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, change your lists to numpy arrays. Then create an array of x variables, instead of one at a time then use it with matrix multiplication to add constraint.  Eg

```
A @ x >= b
```

See example here https://www.cvxpy.org/examples/basic/linear_program.html